# Unable to connect to RDS mysql using sequelize in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sequelize.js

New to serveless & node. I am able to run my sample code locally with out any issues. But when i deploy the same in AWS and test the function always return "module initialization error: Error"

```
db.js
------------
'use strict'
//import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
//var db_mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
var db_mode = 'development'
//var db_mode = 'production'
let env = require('./env.json')[db_mode];
var db = {};
console.log(env); //Am able to see the values in cloud watch
const database = new Sequelize(env.database, env.username, env.password, {
    host: env.host,
    port: env.port,
    logging: false, Disable the logging. It is consuming the time on lambda function.
    dialect: env.dialect,
    define: {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true //prevent sequelize from pluralizing table names
    },
    operatorsAliases: false,
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 20000,
        idle: 10000
    }
});

database.sync()
.then(()=>{
    console.log("connection established successfully")
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log("connection failed")
    console.log(err)
})

module.exports = db;

/*module.exports = {
    'Sequelize': Sequelize,
    'sequelize': sequelize
};*/
```

I am able to see sequelize imported as node_module. Unable to figure out the cause for issue tearing my hair from yesterday turning to you guys to help me understand where might me the issue.

Comment: I am able to use npm package serverless-mysql & connect to RDS MySQL with out any issues. Not able to understand the issue with sequelize

Comment: Does it have to do with node version, using 10.15.0 Lambda runtime is 8.10.0

Comment: Whats the Security Group value for PORT 3306 for your RDS?

Comment: Access is given to security group for lambda function, I am able to connect with serverless-mysql in the same lambda function with out any issues

Comment: added console.log(database) to check if i get a undefined but its printing the sequelize function completely and able to see db values like host, user, port etc getting initialized